# What does "sign" mean in this context?

Tags: terminology

[image]

My lecturer is prone to making mistakes in his slides and I was wondering if this was one of them.

edit: included the whole slide to give more context

Comment: It is impossible to tell without more context.

Comment: What's wrong with the usual interpretation of the sign function?

Comment: @Ant I didn't know about the existence of the sign(signum) function until you just referred to it. Thanks for clearing that up, albeit inadvertently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means tha the sign of $f$
(1, 0, or -1)
is the same as
the sign of
$\cos \theta$.

Answer (score 1):

Given the diagrams and the goal of class assignment, I would say that here 'sign' means literally the algebraic sign of the value - i.e '+' (positive) or '-' (negative).  I.e the vector is assigned to class A when the angle is less than 90 degrees, which occurs when the cosine of the angle is positive; alternately, the vector is assigned to class B when the angle is greater than 90 degrees *[and less than 180 degrees, which is implicit from the way the vector is derived]*, which occurs when the cosine of the angle is negative.  *[the case of exactly 90 degrees isn't handled, but the chances of such a vector are effectively zero]*